# iOS Firebase Swift: A way To Get All Users Using Auth

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to get all signed up users using FirebaseAuth. I know I can create users node and save users when they sign up, but I'm looking for a way to get users using something like `Auth.getAllUsers` since all I'm looking for is `uid` and `displayName`. I'm using swift, so admin sdk seems not supporting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no client-side API to get a list of all users, which is why many developers write details about the users into a database (such as the Firebase Realtime Database, or Cloud Firestore).

There is a server-side Admin SDK that allows listing all users. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users

Answer (score 2):

You can create a cloud function that returns the results of the Admin SDK [list all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) function.  Make sure that you remove any private data fields from the reply, though.  The hashed password, salt, and providers are included in the data.